# Repeating a Click Event in jQuery Without Removing The Previous Click Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function(e) {
       var offset = $(this).offset();
       /*alert("X: " + (e.pageX - offset.left) + " / Y: " + (e.pageY - offset.top));*/
       $(this).after('<h3 class="label">Label</h3>');

       $('.label').offset({ top: e.pageY - offset.top, left: e.pageX - offset.left });

    });
  });
```

```css
.label {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

 <img src="http://mdikici.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/living-room-underlay-glossy-laminate-flooring-with-grey-microfiber-sleeper-sofa-and-nice-indoor-fireplace-in-amazing-minimalist-living-room-design-trendy-minimalist-living-room-design-ideas.jpg" alt="Living Room" title="Living Room" usemap="#tagarea" />

</body>
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Let me clarify what I am trying to achieve, I have an image of a living room with various objects (TV, Sofa, etc) and when I click on say the TV area I want to add a Image Label right next to it, now I have achieved this part but when I click again on any other area say if I clicked on the Sofa then the Image Label disappears from the TV area and shows near the Sofa area, so basically I want this functionality to loop and should be able to add multiple Image Labels.

Please check the script and kindly let me know how to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('img').click(function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            $(this).after('<img src="images/badge.png" alt="Badge" title="Badge" class="label" />');

            $('.label').offset({ top: e.pageY - offset.top, left: e.pageX - offset.left });

      });
    });

    <body><img src="images/living-room-1.jpg" alt="Living Room" title="Living Room" /></body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because although you append a new `img`, your selector of `.label` is changing the position of *all* `img` elements - even those previously added. You need to amend your code to relate to only the new `img` element being added. Try this:

```
$('img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('<img src="images/badge.png" alt="Badge" title="Badge" class="label" />')
        .insertAfter(this)
        .offset({ 
            top: e.pageY - offset.top, 
            left: e.pageX - offset.left 
        });
  });
```

*UPDATE*

Given your updated HTML example and requirements, this should work for you:

```
$('img').click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('<h3 class="label">Label</h3>')
        .insertAfter(this)
        .css({
            top: e.pageY - offset.top,
            left: e.pageX - offset.left
        });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhjyjtvw/3/)

Comment: Hi Rory, That code for some reason removes the Living Room image, so it's not working for me. And if I replace (in my original code) the click event to add a <h3> element instead of the image element I still have the same issue.

Comment: In that case can you please add your full HTML and JS code to your question, as it's hard to diagnose the exact issue without seeing the full problem.

Comment: The body element only has the living room image, I have added the body area code in the question now.

Comment: It could be an issue with using `offset`. Try setting the labels to `position: absolute` in CSS, and then setting their `top` and `left` positions. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qhjyjtvw/2/

Comment: Here's another example using your image and the `h3` element: http://jsfiddle.net/qhjyjtvw/3/

Comment: Thanks again Rory, the script you provided in jsfiddle works.